# Entity Framework CF Something has changed

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, dbcontext, invalidoperationexception

I just got back to an old project that uses Entity Framework and when I run it I get the dreaded "The model backing the ‘MyContext’ context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database ..." error. The problem is that nothing *should* have changed. Is there any way I can proceed to analyze this issue and figure out what changes is causing it?

I have examined the InvalidOperationException I get but I have been unable to find any clues anywhere within.

I would really appreciate some good advice on this one.

Thanks.

Comment: Generate a migration and see what it shows. You can delete the file when done or update-database. You could also do a schema compare from VS2013.

Comment: Good idea but how do I perform a schema compare?

Comment: I followed your advice and found out what the changes where. I then corrected the code. I then removed the migration in the project and in the database (_MigrationHistory) table. But when I run the code I get another error: "Unable to update database to match the current model because there are pending changes and automatic migration is disabled". I don't want automatic migration but where does EF get the "pending" changes from? Are there more stuff that needs to be removed after I run an "add-migration"?

Comment: What I do is comment out all the code in the Up() / Down() methods of the migration then do an update-database. Then I remove the migration and EF won't prompt me again.

Comment: Thanks again Steve, that worked. But how does EF keep track of the migrations? I assumed it used the migration .cs files and the _MigrationHistory table. But having removed my "bogus" migration file that I just ran to find out what had changed in my entities and then making sure the corresponding line in the _MigrationHistory table got deleted, EF got confused and calculated the need to remove some columns in some other tables that didn't even exist. So, apparently the EF automagic is relies on some other info, but where does EF record it?

Comment: Steve: If you'd like to take the time and convert your comments into a reply I'd be happy to mark it as an Answer.